# Website for writing project management

Tags: formatting

Basically, I'm looking for something like Scrivener or other similar software, but online. Do such sites exist?

I'm looking for something that allows you to manage your writing project, all aspects of it - characters, story, chapters, timeline, etc. And yes, it would be perfect if everything is in the same site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps someday [novlr.org](http://novlr.org) will be like an online scrivener. I'm a big fan of it, and they are very actively pushing out new features ..so have a look.

Ps I'm not affiliated to them whatsoever.

Comment: This pretty much sounds exactly like what he wants and not going to lie, it has me curious too.  I may take a look at it myself lol

Answer (score 0):

1. Google Docs

   This is like MS Office, only online. You have a wordprocessor, a spreadsheet app (for characters and plotting), and so on.

   Many writers write in Office, so Google Docs will work just as well, if that is the kind of writer you are.
2. Set up your own webspace with whatever tools you want

   You could have a private, password protected wiki on your webspace. There are free, open source as well as paid tools available for almost any task you can imagine, from mindmapping to outlining to organising complex information and typesetting.

Comment: To add to this, Apple has their own version of google docs.  You can log into their web portal via icloud.com and access your pages docs through that and type it all through the browser.  Making it really nice to slip between PC and apple based products and locations.  You can create your own file system and what not too just like google docs.

Answer (score 0):

[Celtx](https://www.celtx.com/index.html) can be used online and it's particularly good for scripts.

Comment: Great option for people writing movies!  Unfortunately though, after a quick look at the link, I don't see this allowing him to write a novel from it as it is heavily aimed at film making.  Might be worth a shot though if they provide a free trial to see if it can do what he needs.